# show percentage difference with arrows in excel chart

Tags: excel, graph

I have an idea in mind but no idea how to complete it or if it is even possible, therefore I ask for your help.

I have a graph (made up) that shows an outcome of two different years and I have to look at the procentage difference for each period.

For example, period 1: tot2016=456 and tot2017=478 then we can se that in 2017 there was 4,8% more of whatever I have to calculate, and then so on for all periods.

I know that I can get a secondary axis to how the percentage but it just looks horrible, therefore I would like to have arrows on the bottom red and gren and corresponding percentage change for each period. Potential outcome can be seen in homemade paint picture.


[image]

Can someone please help me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom data labels and show the cell values in it

please refer this: http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/05/05/change-data-labels-in-charts/

[image]